# multi-hop tunnel in the background; killing local tunnel does not kill remote tunnel

Tags: ssh, tunnel

**Multi-hop tunnel:**

I am opening a tunnel to a remote server via a jump server.

```
ssh ${JUMP_HOST} -l ${JUMP_HOST_USER} -L ${PORT}:localhost:${PORT} \
    ssh ${REMOTE_HOST} -l ${REMOTE_HOST_USER} -L ${PORT}:localhost:${PORT}
```

Now when I open a connection to `localhost:port` it will forward to  `jump:port` which in turn will forward to `remote:port`

**Run local tunnel in background:**

The problem with this is that it opens a shell on `remote`, whereas I just want the tunnel to run in the background.

So I add the `-f` option to my local tunnel to request it run in the background

```
ssh -f ${JUMP_HOST} -l ${JUMP_HOST_USER} -L ${PORT}:localhost:${PORT} \
    ssh ${REMOTE_HOST} -l ${REMOTE_HOST_USER} -L ${PORT}:localhost:${PORT}
```

This, however, returns an error:

```
Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal.
```

Presumably this error is coming from the tunnel from `jump` to `remote`, and is caused because `stdin` is closed when my local tunnel is daemonized.

**Tell remote tunnel I won't be running a command:**

I then tried running the `jump-> remote` tunnel with `-N` to tell it I'm not going to be running a remote command.

```
ssh -f ${JUMP_HOST} -l ${JUMP_HOST_USER} -L ${PORT}:localhost:${PORT} \
    ssh -N ${REMOTE_HOST} -l ${REMOTE_HOST_USER} -L ${PORT}:localhost:${PORT}
```

This works great - the tunnel runs in the background and I can connect successfully to `remote:port` by connecting to `localhost:port`.

**Problem:**

The problem I'm having is when I want to close the tunnels.

If I send a kill signal to my local ssh tunnel's pid, it will close, but the ssh tunnel running on `jump` remains running.

It seems that when I daemonize my local tunnel, the tunnel on `jump` is also daemonized.

**Question:**

Is it possible to run my local tunnel in the background, but when I kill it, have it shut down all the tunnels it has spawned on all remote servers?

Comment: Does your ssh client not support `-J` (jumphost) yet?

Comment: @grawity looks like not. 
`$ ssh -V 
OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.4, OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016
`

Comment: Then you should use -W with ProxyCommand. It's like -L but specifically for this kind of usage... There are existing posts here on SU about it.

Answer (score 2):

Run both `ssh`-s locally. First connect to the jump server and create a tunnel that will allow you to `ssh` to the remote host from the *local* computer:

```
ssh -fN $jump_host -l $jump_host_user -L ${helper_port}:${remote_host}:22
```

Then use this tunnel to connect to the remote host, creating the desired tunnel; still from the local computer:

```
ssh -fN localhost -p $helper_port -l ${remote_host_user} -L ${port}:localhost:${port}
```

Since the two `ssh` processes are local, you can `kill` them both whenever you like; but I think killing the first one should be enough, try it.

---

Notes:

- This approach may be inconvenient if your "secondary" `ssh` relies on specific config stored in `ssh_config` on the jump host.
- I used lowercase variable names; see [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/42849/108618).