# How to forward a port through 2 clients via SSH?

Tags: linux, networking, ssh, port-forwarding, vnc

I am trying to access a remote VNC server (say server) via SSH. I am able to do it through one client (say client1):

**Client 1** (works fine):

```
ssh -L  5901:localhost:5900 server` and then `vncviewer localhost:5901
```

Now, I connect to client1 from another client (say client2), and try to access the server's VNC session.

**Client 2**:

```
ssh -L 5901:localhost:5901 client1` and then `vncviewer localhost:5901`
```

Then I get the following error on the SSH prompt:

```
channel 4: open failed: connect failed: Connection refused
```

and the VNC client states that the server closed the connection. (EDIT)

I precise I do not try to connect with 2 clients to an unshared VNC session. I believe the problem to be related to port forwarding or perhaps SSH.

What can I be missing?

Comment: "Then I get the following error on the SSH prompt" -- which `ssh` prompt? On client2? Are you keeping the `ssh` on client1 running at the time?

Comment: Yes. I actually use client1 for bouncing: I connect from client2 to client1 and then from client1 to server.

Comment: I don't know (yet) why you get the error. You may try [this approach](https://superuser.com/a/1321241/432690) and run both `ssh`-s on client2. Maybe it will shed some light on the issue.

Answer (score 0):

As was pointed out, [this thread](https://superuser.com/a/1321241/432690) contains the solution: Rather than SSH bouncing, I just needed client1 to forward server's port 5900. So on client2:

```
ssh -L 5901:server:5900 client1
```

And that's it! Thanks a lot Kamil Maciorowski!

By the way, I tried Winnie Tigger's solution, but my VNC client couldn't the server this way...

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure if I got you right.
You have an existing connection between client1 and the remote server. Than you ssh into client1 from client2 and try to start vncviewer on client1?

If so, you dont need a port forwarding of port 5901 between client1 and client2. You rather need something called X-Fowarding. On client1 configure your sshd.conf that X-forwarding is allowed and than use "ssh -X client1" on client2 to connect to client1 and there start your vncviewer.

But be aware that this construct will not perform very well.